# Ошибка с отображением фигур с turtle в Python

Tags: python

```
import turtle


def circle(a = 12):
    myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
    myTurtle.circle(int(a))
    turtle.exitonclick()

def square(a = 50):
    myTurtle_2 = turtle.Turtle()
    myTurtle_2.forward(int(a))
    myTurtle_2.left(90)
    myTurtle_2.forward(int(a))
    myTurtle_2.left(90)
    myTurtle_2.forward(int(a))
    myTurtle_2.left(90)
    myTurtle_2.forward(int(a))
    myTurtle_2.left(90)
    turtle.exitonclick()
```

Вызывая функцию:

```
circle()   -   рисует круг



square()  - выбивает ошибку - Turtle.Terminal
```

То есть функция срабабтывает только один раз
Почему так происходит? Мне нужно чтобы в программе рисовалось несколько фигур.

Answer (score 2):

Не надо делать `turtle.exitonclick()` в конце каждой функции. Сделайте один раз в конце всего скрипта.

Ну и ещё пара советов:

1). В вашем случае совсем не обязательно в каждой функции создавать экземпляр turtle.Turtle(). Можно создать его один раз перед функциями и использовать тот же экземпляр в обеих функциях. А можно вообще ничего не создавать и просто вызывать те же функции из самого модуля.

2). Одинаковые строчки проще загнать в цикл. В итоге то, что вы хотите, получается гораздо меньшим количеством кода.

```
import turtle


def circle(a = 12):
    turtle.circle(int(a))


def square(a = 50):
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(int(a))
        turtle.left(90)


circle()
square()

turtle.exitonclick()
```